# How to set one coordinate of a geometry from another mesh in three.js

Tags: three.js

What I'm trying to do is to "drape" some points on a PlaneGeometry. I have the planar coordinates of the points in the same coordinate system of my plane geometry, what I need i sto get the "height" from the plane to position the points on top of it.

What's the best way to achieve it? Querying the planar mesh in Javascript would be to heavy. Should it be done (and could it be done) using the vertex shader?

**EDIT**

Probably using a ray caster is the right solution, something like shown in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast

**EDIT2**

Raycasting does the job, but it's quite slow for a lot of objects. I suppose there are more efficient ways to do that...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13861666/2014-01-17%2011_27_15-firenze.png

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, please? Perhaps provide an illustration?

Comment: Let's say I have a PlanaGeometry, representing a terrain, and a set of points without "height" information. I need to place the points on the planar geometry surface.

(I don't know why I can't get Stackoverflow to inform me about comments)

Comment: Add each point as a child of the plane, so they are all in the same coordinate system. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Mmm, this is the result I would like to obtain http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/conf/SANTA_FE_CD-ROM/sf_papers/mitas_lubos/img/gel.gif  
I'm not sure setting it as a child will give that result. Does it?

Comment: var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.9, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  sphere.overdraw = true;
  sphere.position.set( 0.5, 2.1, 0);
  plane.add(sphere);
  

The result is that the sphere are correctly positioned for x and y, but z is, obviously set to 0. How do I tell them to obtain z from the plane?
Image 1: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13861666/2014-01-17%2010_06_29-firenze.png
Image 2: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13861666/2014-01-17%2010_05_58-firenze.png

Comment: I see.., you do not know the height of the surface at each point. Yes, raycasting can tell you that. What renderer are you using?... `THREE.SphereGeometry(0.9, 100, 100)` has way more faces than you need. Try [ 0.9, 24, 12 ] instead... Are you using `CanvasRenderer`.